# Google home to read local webpage and answer questions using Javascript

Tags: javascript, actions-on-google, google-home

I would like to use Google Home to read from a local webpage and answer questions based on the content of that webpage using Javascript. Is that possible?

Comment: The question is too broad as it stands, but if you can update the question provide specific details, it may help narrow it down so we can answer. Can you clarify what you mean by "local" in this case? What have you tried and where are you having the problems? Can you give a detailed example?

Comment: +1 to @Prisoner - If you wish to let your assistant app read a web page you can do it with a webhook. The page could not be hosted 'locally' as there is no web server inside Google home device. For more about creating assistant apps with web hooks you can try this code lab that I wrote: bit.ly/aog-bitcoin-codelab good luck!

Comment: @Prisoner a local web page that is hosted on my local machine, not an online webpage! I am fairly new to developing actions for google assistant and i have only tried the basic question/answer apps

Answer (score 0):

Your question still remains fairly broad, but in short, the answer is no.

Your Google Home only communicates with Google servers and does not have the ability to communicate on a LAN. It does not run your Actions on the device itself - Actions must have a publicly accessible URL that Google's servers can communicate with.

The current best practice to have internal information available outside the LAN is to make it available via a cloud resource of some sort. If you're just getting started, a Firebase Database is a reasonable approach.

This also allows your Assistant (for example, the one on your phone) to run outside your LAN and still have access and control of the devices in your LAN through the cloud resources.